# Ubuntu 20.04.3 audio not working with asus z690e

Tags: asus

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.3 on my pc. I7-12700k, asus rog strix z690e gaming wifi. The audio does not seem to work in sound settings of Ubuntu and I have no clue about what I should try because I am a noob at Linux. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Look up how to install sound drivers for Ubuntu on your type of ASUS Laptop. The best place to look for how to do that is the ASUS website. However I doubt it is the drivers. I think it is an issue to do with the player you are using that is lacking the necessary plugins to playback the type of media file you have there. Your best approach now is to install VLC Media Player and see if it will play back your media file. Install VLC Media Player from your Software Updates option.

Comment: I’m using a custom pc. Furthermore, there is no audio whatsoever through my headphones. My headphones work fine with other devices and windows on the same pc. I am confident that it is an os problem. Are their certain audio packages I need to install?

Comment: If you are new to Linux, install "VLC Media Player" in your Ubuntu. You shall figure out things along the way as you gain more experience on working on Linux and the Software Copyrights involved. "VLC Media Player" should suffice for now.

Comment: Vlc is only for files but I can’t hear anything from my system. I hear no audio.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue on rog strix z690-a gaming wifi d4. sound works fine in windows 10, however, in ubuntu 20.04 it doesnt work. did you find how to fix this?